# Lifehacker feed no longer working

Tags: rss, lifehacker

I've had a custom feed from Lifehacker for over a year that's worked with no problem. It uses their tag format to narrow which posts I get. The URL for my feedreader looks like this:

```
http://lifehacker.com/software/not:AOL/not:vista/not:Apple/not:Audio/not:GTD/not:Mac/not:Mac%20OS%20X/not:Family/not:Kids/not:Parenting/not:Cars/index.xml
```

The past few days, it hasn't sent anything through, even though I know there are posts out there that fit my criteria. Does anyone know why it no longer works? Have they changed something in response to the gawker sites being hacked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be best to post your question to the [Lifehacker Data Breach Q&A page](http://lifehacker.com/5712975/lifehacker-data-breach-qa-were-here-to-help) where they seem to be readily (and quickly) responding to any queries about this.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't seem to find anything like that when I was there earlier.